# Change storage type in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

What will be the best, fastest and easiest way for an offline task of replacing Google Cloud SQL storage type from SSD to HDD or from HDD to SSD with very large storage (in my case more than 1.8TB)?

Answer (score 0):

Just like [storage capacity](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen) can not be changed, you can't change the storage type.

[image]